# is there a more 'pythonic' way to generate a string from a list with customized separators

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way to generate a string from  a list than the one below that works.

Disclaimer: I am a biophysicist, with not an advanced knowledge of python and did search it and test combinations like: `resid {}` or `.format(a) / ([a]) / (*a) / (x for x in a)` extensively, but probably I do not know what to look for... I know the code below works, but I do not clearly understand why any of the listed does not.

input:

```
a=[23,33,105,400]
```

Code:

```
c=""
for x in a[0:-1]: 
     c = c + "resid {} or ".format(x)
c=c+"resid {}".format(a[-1])
print(c)
```

output:

```
resid 23 or resid 33 or resid 105 or resid 400
```

Comment: What is meant by any of the listed does not?

Comment: any of this attmpts resid {} or ".format(a) / ([a]) / (*a) / (x for x in a)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use string-joining

```
" or ".join("resid {}".format(x) for x in [23,33,105,400])
# 'resid 23 or resid 33 or resid 105 or resid 400'
```

You can also use f-strings

```
" or ".join(f'resid {x}' for x in [23,33,105,400])
```

Comment: Upvote for the f-string. Requires Python 3.7 though, right? OP should check version.

Comment: They were added in 3.6. If OP is using Python2, should definitely switch to Python3

Comment: criket_007: Works nice, thanks. A question: why if "or" is first in the statement ended before "resid"? and the last "or" is not written...

Comment: @MarioABianchet `" or "` is applied last, actually. From the list of numbers, you form a list of strings `['resid 23', 'resid 33' ...]`, then you join the strings using a delimiter of `" or "` in between each element

Answer (score 1):

You can create a format string as follows:

```
format_string = (len(a)-1) * 'resid {} or ' + 'resid {} '
```

then apply a to it by:

```
print(format_string.format(*a))
```